# How to Speed Up Load Time of RSS Feed?

Tags: php, html, xml, web, rss

I'm using feedroll.com for my site to receive 4 different feeds.  After testing the page speed, it's obvious the RSS is slowing down the site by far and taking the longest to load.  Any general tips on how to somehow minimize the page load time for RSS feeds?  Thanks.

- side note: I'm using the feeds because I have one site where parts of it are JSP and other parts PHP (Wordpress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach (if the content of the feeds do not change very much over time): Use a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_job) to download the feeds periodically to your web server. Take the downloaded feeds from your web server's file system when you serve documents to the client.

For example: If you use the [Feedcombiner](http://feedroll.com/feedcombiner/) you can periodically download the feed to your server and make a link to this downloaded RSS Feed on your server's file system.